# how do I scrape text from same and same class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, screen-scraping

[my python code]
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfGSS.png)

I am not able to scrape 'points' . Number of matches have same tag and class ,so I am getting number of matches instead of point. I am new to this ,can anyone please help me.
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post minimal, reproducible code, not an image so others can reproduce and troubleshoot the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also applying the find_all function to the parts in the for-loop?
Also, you can split at the end, to get the entries as single strings in a list.